# How to plot histogram for group-by data in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm new to Tableau. May I have a question to plot histogram?

My Tableau Data Source is:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| StudentID (str)| Subject (str) |  Grade (int) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1              | English       |  90          |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I want to generate a column:

```
SELECT avg(Grade) as avg_grade FROM table
GROUP BY StudentID
```

Then I want to plot a **histogram** for `avg_grade`:

- Horizontal axis: binned region 0-10, 10-20, ..., 90-100
- Vertical axis: count of number of StudentID in each bin

I do not know what is the right terminologies for these operations (GROUP BY, bin the GROUP BY) in Tableau. Could you please help me how to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a LOD calculated field called **Avg_Student_Grade** defined as:

```
{ FIXED [StudentID] : AVG([Grade]) }
```

Then Right click on that new field in the data pane (left margin) and choose "Create->Bins ..." Set the bin size to 10.

Then put the new bin field on Columns and some count field on Rows. In this case, you should likely use COUNTD([StudentID]) for count distinct.

Play with the mark type, and whether to make the bin field discrete or continuous. Format to taste.